# Clickhouse jdbc schema [Airbyte integration]

Tags: java, jdbc, etl, clickhouse

I'm really looking for and advice on how to set up data streaming between Oracle db (just for example) and Clickhouse database using Airbyte ETL tool.

I've created the source and destination connectors and successfuly tested the connections but now I'm facing the issue in syncing the data. While the source is sending the data correctly, the destination (Clickhouse) JDBC driver requires the schema to accept those tables.

So, I don't know how to retrieve this schema and where it should be stored. Maybe there're some means to create this schema, because when I inspect the log it displays such thing:
[image]

So, basically, the error is connected with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: jdbc destinations must specify a schema.`

Please I will be really grateful for providing any means for resolving that issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use should try version 0.1.1 of ClickHouse destination. It fixes your issue https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/pull/8982

Comment: basicaly, currently a new version is available that solves the problem with jdbc schema in clickhouse destination connectors and also there were issues with basic normalization. so today these two features are ready to go. Appreciate your efforts, Konstantin! Thanks